# How do I route multiple domains in Apache to multiple Django projects?

Tags: django, python-2.7, apache2, django-1.7, django-1.8

So i'll start off by explaining my goal. I have multiple domains that I am routing to a simple IP address on my server. I want Apache to route each domain to the appropriate `wsgi.py` file in its Django project. It seems the official Docs are written for handling one domain per server. Here they are if you want to check them [Docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) I would also like to note that I don't really want to use the Django sites framework because it seems its not geared for what I need.

So i'll show you what I have been trying. Iv'e placed this inside the `sites-available/000-default.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com

    Alias /media/ /path/to/foo.com/media/
    Alias /static/ /path/to/foo.com/static/

    <Directory /path/to/foo.com/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/foo.com/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/foo.com/foo/wsgi.py

    <Directory /path/to/foo.com/foo>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo2.com
    ServerAlias foo2.com

    Alias /media/ /path/to/foo2.com/media/
    Alias /static/ /path/to/foo2.com/static/

    <Directory /path/to/foo2.com/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/foo2.com/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/foo2.com/foo2/wsgi.py

    <Directory /path/to/foo2.com/foo2>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Oddly enough, neither site loads. I just get a Apache just serves my an empty file index page. Note that I don't have `WSGIPythonPath /path/to/foo2.com/` included. I get an error when I include it. And i'm not entirely sure its needed.

Things iv'e also done.

- Set a ServerName in the `apache2.conf` file.
- Modified the `wsgi.py` file to handle multiple sites.
- Iv'e also tried setting my IP in the `/etc/hosts` file.

So that's mainly all of it. Iv'e searched all over the internet and I could not find any solutions that are up to date. If you know of a way to solve this, please let me know. If at all possible, try to include code with your answers.

PS.  I'm running this in Ubuntu Server 14.04 with python 2.7.

Comment: In the second VirtualHost, the Directory path for ``wsgi.py`` does not match the WSGIScriptAlias path. Does it change anything if you fix that?

Comment: That was my mistake while I was typing it out here. But no, that does not fix my problem.